# Ошибка в запросе SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

```
$connection=mysql_connect($db_address,$db_login,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
$sql_create_db="CREATE DATABASE wup_wup";
mysql_query($sql_create_db) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(wup_wup) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_create_table="CREATE TABLE nelson(
datas DATE ,price INT,strop INT)";
mysql_query($sql_create_table) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_insert_into_table_nelson="INSERT INTO nelson VALUES(19950712,34,12),(19910712,14,2),(19991212,4,7),(1990-21-12,6,7)";
mysql_query($sql_insert_into_table_nelson) or  die(mysql_error());

$sql2="SELECT datas FROM TABLE nelson WHERE price<7";
mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Ошибка в последних 2 строчках

Comment: `mysql_select_db(wup_wup)` - чойто `wup_wup` не в кавычках?

Comment: @zloctb, [В чем ошибка?](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/09/blog-post_24.html).

Comment: @Iranda, убивайте вопрос!

Comment: чем плохая тема?neoascetic

Comment: Об этом написано по ссылке от @Iranda. Вопрос - не интересен. Дело в вашей невнимательности, а не в интересной технической проблеме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT datas FROM **TABLE** nelson WHERE price<7

`TABLE` - лишнее

[MySQL SELECT reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: спасибо очень